# Javascript page refresh and retaining the params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I have this page with params coming from previous page.  When I refresh the page, params will be gone and youtube video will not be displayed.

You can see this effect from the url here: https://gamecrawl.com/play/xOqFjTR9LG0

```
{
    path: "/play/:id?",
    component: _644a45f8,
    name: "play-id"
  },
```

Is there a way to retain them so the video is displayed properly?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="text-5xl mt-6">{{ $route.params.title }}</h1>

    <div class="bg-gray-100">
      <div class="flex content-center px-16 py-8 mt-2">
        <iframe
          width="854"
          height="480"
          :src="youtubeurl"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>

      <p class="p-8">
        {{ $route.params.description }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["ytid", "description", "title"],
  mounted() {
    console.log("item id");
    console.log(this.ytid);
  },
  computed: {
    youtubeurl() {
      return "https://youtube.com/embed/" + this.$route.params.ytid;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Take a look at [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html). Using the store concept from vuex you will be able to keep all of the data in the `state` of you application.Than you can retrieve it when needed.

Comment: If you litterally hit the real url, with all the params, using window.location or something alike. Wouldnt that do the trick?

Comment: Can you add your router file code for this particular route? That will help figure out what's the best way to handle this.

Comment: I just tried using localstorage and it works after refreshing.

Comment: That will do it, but fwiw, your param is labeled as `id?` in your route, but it looks like you're trying to use `this.$route.params.ytid`, so there is a mismatch between `id` and `ytid`. I would try just `id` in the route, and then you should be able to access it regardless of refreshing at `this.$route.params.id`.

Comment: @SeanBeck shouldn't be caused by that.  Since it is now working with local storage, I will just stick with it for now.